# jekyll template not rendering correctly on github page

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Does anyone know why the initial jekyll template not rendering correctly on the github page(http://miml.github.io/imiml/), while it is looking perfectly on my localhost:4000.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why this question was closed ? If it's unclear for you maybe one can understand and give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `_config.yml` set `baseurl: /imiml`

Comment: but now I can't run on the localhost anymore... tried to converted back to the original code... still getting Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000/imiml/ Please help!

Comment: Set to `baseurl: ""`. But the fact that `jekyll serve` is serving on `0.0.0.0:4000/iminl` is not bad, you index page is at this address and it mimics the production environment.

Comment: Just quickly re-setup the project again. All good. Thanks heaps!

Comment: I guess it's something to do with the _config.yml again. Having the same set of code, it runs perfectly on github pages as well as my localhost, just having a similar issue I had before, this time on the live site: http://imiml.com . Have you experienced it before?

Comment: Now you have a custom domain, you have to set `baseurl: ""` and `url: http://imiml.com/`

Comment: You're a Jeckyll genius! Thanks again!